# Taking expectation in proof of Markov inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

In Probability and Computing (Mitzenmacher & Upfal), Markov inequality is proven roughly as follows:

(Theorem) Markov's Inequality. Let $X$ be a random variable that assumes only nonnegative values. Then, for all $a > 0$,
$$
\Pr(X \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{a}
$$

Proof:

For $a > 0$, let

- $I = 1 \text{ if } X \geq a$
- $I = 0 \text{ otherwise }$

We also have
$$
I \leq \frac{X}{a}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[I] = \Pr(X \geq a)
$$

(so far so good)

Now they "take expectation" of the inequality
$$
\mathbb{E}[I] \leq \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{X}{a} \right]
$$

Why is this a "legitimate move"? Let's simplify:
$$
g(X) \leq X \implies \mathbb{E}[g(X)] \leq \mathbb{E}(X)
$$
Maybe it's very easy but why does this inequality with expectations hold? Does it have something to do with Jensen's inequality? Or something even simpler?

Comment: This simply stems from the fact that if $f \le g$ pointwise, then the integral of $f$ is also $\le$ the integral of $g$.

Comment: Maybe this reframing will "click" for you (although it is not really any different than sbares's comment): if $X \le Y$, we want to show $E[X] \le E[Y]$. It is equivalent to show that $Y-X \ge 0$ implies $E[Y-X] \ge 0$, which follows if you understand that the average of a nonnegative random variable should also be nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you both, problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @sbares and @angryavian! Here I summed up their answers:

$$g(X) \leq X \iff 0 \leq X - g(X)$$

Expectation of a non-negative random variable (here: $X - g(X)$) must be also non-negative, so

$$0 \leq X - g(X) \implies 0 \leq \mathbb{E}[X - g(X)]$$

Now by linearity of expectation

$$
0 \leq \mathbb{E}[X - g(X)] \iff 0 \leq \mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[g(X)]
\iff
\mathbb{E}[g(X)] \leq \mathbb{E}[X]
$$

(just substitute $I$ and $\frac{X}{a}$ into the original proof above)