# Bernoulli variable in proof of Markov inequality

Tags: probability-theory

In Probability and Computing (Mitzenmacher & Upfal), Markov inequality is proven roughly as follows:

> (Theorem) Markov's Inequality. Let $X$ be a random variable that assumes only nonnegative values. Then, for all $a > 0$,
> $$
> \Pr(X \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{a}
> $$
>
> Proof:
>
> For $a > 0$, let
>
> - $I = 1 \text{ if } X \geq a$ with probability $\Pr(X \geq a)$
> - $I = 0 \text{ otherwise }$ (with probability $\Pr(X < a)$)

and so on (discussed also here: [Taking expectation in proof of Markov inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4443168/taking-expectation-in-proof-of-markov-inequality) )

While I do understand that we transform $X$ into zero or one given the value of $X$

> $I = 1 \text{ if } X \geq a$

I only **intuitively** (not rigorously) understand the probability of taking 1

> with probability $\Pr(X \geq a)$

Why is that so exactly? (I would appreciate an answer **without** measure theory, if possible)

Comment: You are correct that the definition of $I$ is confusing (it mixes the definition with a probability fact). A better definition of $I$ is $$I= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \mbox{ if $X\geq a$} \\ 0 & \mbox{ else} \end{array}\right.$$ From this it holds that $aI\leq X$ and so $E[aI]\leq E[X]$. You can compute $E[aI]$ using linearity of expectation and the fact $\{I=1\}\iff \{X\geq a\}$.

Comment: The last fact $\{ I = 1\} \iff \{X \geq a\}$ is interesting -- so these are two sets, but what are they? For $\{X \geq a\}$ I would say $\{s \in \Omega : X(s) \geq a\}$ so it's an event.. which is the same for $I$ because of the mapping function... so they must have the same probability... right?

Comment: Yes, those two events are the same so they have the same probability. Indeed an event is a subset of the sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer just summarizes my comments with slightly different notation.
Suppose $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable that is surely nonnegative:
$$X(\omega)\geq 0 \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega$$
Fix $a>0$. A crisp definition of $I:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is
$$ I(\omega)= \left\{\begin{array}{c}
1 & \mbox{if $X(\omega)\geq a$} \\
0 & \mbox{ else} 
\end{array}\right.$$
It can be seen that
$$ a I(\omega) \leq X(\omega) \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega$$

> Exercise: Why is this true? Where are we using the fact that $X$ is nonnegative? Hint: Consider those $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $I(\omega)=0$, then consider those for which $I(\omega)=1$.

More compactly, we can write
$$ aI \leq X$$
Taking expectations of both sides gives
$$aE[I] \leq E[X]$$
Now we can find the expectation of the Bernoulli random variable $I$ and relate it to $P[X\geq a]$ by the observation
$$ \{I=1\}\iff\{X\geq a\}$$
which is indeed the same as saying
$$\{\omega \in \Omega : I(\omega)=1\} = \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)\geq a\}$$
so that $\omega$ is an element of the set on the left-hand-side if and only if $\omega$ is an element of the set on the right-hand-side.